# Permission denied when running "./script.sh", but works when running "bash script.sh"

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I've got an issue executing a simple .sh file

Here is my example :

**I'm creating a simple "abc.sh" file for creating a folder**

```
 echo 'mkdir abc' > abc.sh
```

**According the executable bit**

```
 chmod +x abc.sh
```

**Trying to run the sh file**

```
 ./abc.sh
```

**Permission denied (french version)**

```
 bash: ./abc.sh: Permission non accordée
```

**But when I do "bash ./abc.sh" instead of "./abc.sh", the script is running**

Have you an idea for this ?

Answer (score 3):

Issue resolved..

I just found this post : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203371/run-script-sh-vs-bash-script-sh-permission-denied

The filesystem was mounted with the "noexec" param.

Comment: Okay, kindly accept your own answer to mark this question as solved.