# Bash script not creating file from crontab

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I have already tried half of askubuntu but still not succeeding. 
I got the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test" > "/mnt/ssd/test.txt"
echo "test"
```

And the following crontab -e line:

```
* * * * * /mnt/ssd/test.sh > /mnt/ssd/cron.log
```

When I add a line to the cron.log file manually, it will be empty each new minute what tells me the cron is being fired.

I also tried the following cronjob:

```
* * * * * env > /mnt/ssd/env.output
```

This gave me these values:

```
LANGUAGE=nl_NL.UTF-8
HOME=/home/pi
LOGNAME=pi
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
LC_ALL=nl_NL.UTF-8
PWD=/home/pi
```

It again tells me the cron is working and the SHELL is correct right?

I tried this cron as well:

```
* * * * * PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin /mnt/ssd/test.sh > /mnt/ssd/cron.log
```

Neither this writes anything to the cron.log file or is creating the test.txt file.

I am kinda confused. If my PATH is wrong am I trying to correct this in the right manner or is something else incorrect?

EDIT:
thanks to @steeldrive it was found that the drive this script was located on was mounted with noexec type. Meaning a bash file can not normally be executed. Placing 'bash' in front of the command made it work. The command now looks like:

```
* * * * * bash /mnt/ssd/test.sh > /mnt/ssd/cron.log 2>&1
```

the 2>&1 is added so errors would also be outputted to the log file.

Comment: Is the script executable? can the user whose crontab you used write to /mnt/ssd? what does `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` show?

Comment: @steeldriver yes it is executable and does what it should using the terminal itself. output: (pi) CMD (PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin /mnt/ssd/test.sh > /mnt/ssd/cron.log)
and also:  (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output) (because of mail but this should not matter right?)

Comment: if you want to append line to a file you should use ```>>```

Comment: It may be helpful to add `2>&1` to capture any errors in the log file as well. I don't think your `PATH` is the issue since everything you're using is either absolute or a shell builtin

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: /mnt/ssd/test.sh: Permission denied 
Which is weard because this file has been given 777 permissions

Comment: you mean cron.log, test.txt?

Comment: @bac0n i have no clue what it means. the test.sh file has 777 permissions and this message shows in cron.log

Comment: Is /mnt/ssd mounted with the `noexec` option? check the output of `mount | grep ssd`

Comment: @steeldriver /dev/sda1 on /mnt/ssd type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)

Comment: @Mart right - so it **is** mounted `noexec` and hence won't be directly executable - although you should still be able to use `bash /mnt/ssd/test.sh`. See for example [Permission denied when running “./script.sh”, but works when running “bash script.sh”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756218/permission-denied-when-running-script-sh-but-works-when-running-bash-scrip)

Comment: Wauw, oke this just made it work by adding 'bash' in front of the command. You are my hero!

Comment: I think you should take the time and write an answer, @Mart since you know the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, based on the input given by @steeldriver, we managed to obtain a solution.

The bash script is located on a mount which has been mounted by the noexec type. Meaning the bash files cannot be executed straightforward. 
This was found using the command:

```
mount | grep ssd
```

The solution however is simple: add bash in front of the crontab -e command:

```
* * * * * bash /mnt/ssd/test.sh > /mnt/ssd/cron.log 2>&1
```

The 2>&1 part is added in this line as well so the error logs are also placed inside the cron.log file.